# Monkeypatch ActiveRecord::FinderMethods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to monkey patch ActiveRecord::FinderMethods in order to use hashed ids for my models. So for example User.find(1) becomes User.find("FEW"). Sadly my overwritten method doesn't get called. Any ideas how to overwrite the find_one method?

```
module ActiveRecord
  module FinderMethods
    alias_method :orig_find_one, :find_one
    def find_one(id)
      if id.is_a?(String)
        orig_find_one decrypt_id(id)
      else
        orig_find_one(id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is probably a really bad idea, it could break things internally. Why not write your own alternate method and use that in your controllers? `find_hashed_id` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'm going with find_hashed_id :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article that discusses how to actually do what you want by overriding the `User.primary_key` method like:

```
class User
  self.primary_key = 'hashed_id'
end
```

Which would allow you to call `User.find` and pass it the "hashed_id":

http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/

So, it's possible.

That said, I would recommend against doing that, and instead using something like `User.find_by_hashed_id`.  The only difference is that this method will return `nil` when a result is not found instead of throwing an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception.  You could throw this manually in your controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_hashed_id(hashed_id)
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.new if @user.nil?
  ... continue processing ...
end
```

Finally, one other note to make this easier on you -- Rails also has a method you can override in your model, `to_param`, to tell it what property to use when generating routes.  By default, of course, it users the id, but you would probably want to use the hashed_id.

```
class User
  def to_param
    self.hashed_id
  end
end
```

Now, in your controller, `params[:id]` will contain the hashed_id instead of the id.

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_hashed_id(params[:id])
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.new if @user.nil?
  ... continue processing ...
end
```

Comment: I've sometimes called the opposite of `to_param` to be a class-level method called `from_param` for situations like this if this sort of ID hiding is pervasive. This is a nice, thorough answer, but it's worth mentioning that `if @user.nil?` is over-kill. First of all, `@user` is never going to be `false`, so `unless @user` would suffice, but if you use `find_by_hashed_id!` it will raise that error for you automatically.

Comment: I wasn't aware that those extra finder methods supported "!", that's great to know, thanks.  And yeah, `nil?` is a habit I've yet to shake!

Comment: Like `save` which returns an error and `save!` which throws an exception there's usually an exception throwing version of any given ActiveRecord method. One of the things that's a little unnerving about Ruby at first is how only `nil` and `false` are logically false values, `0` and `""` are still truthful. It's just that once you embrace that your code can be a lot simpler. Other languages require a lot of work to differentiate between `0` and false. In Rails you do have `.present?` if you care about how much substance your object has.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you should be careful when doing this, but it is possible.

If you have a method `decode_id` that converts a hashed ID back to the original id, then the following will work:

**In User.rb**

```
# Extend AR find method to allow finding records by an encoded string id:
def self.find(*ids)
  return super if ids.length > 1

  # Note the short-circuiting || to fall-back to default behavior
  find_by(id: decode_id(ids[0])) || super
end
```

Just make sure that `decode_id` returns nil if it's passed an invalid hash. This way you can find by Hashed ID and standard ID, so if you had a user with id 12345, then the following:

```
User.find(12345)
User.find("12345")
User.find(encode_id(12345))
```

Should all return the same user.